# Icons not loading for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm trying to build a chrome extension.
I have created an images folder in the root directory of the extension, and included the icon file names in the manifest.json
When I load the extension in Chrome Dev, the icon doesn't show up. A default icon is used (letter B) and the blue puzzle piece is used in the toolbar button.
Am I doing something wrong?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Blah",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "description": "blah",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Ratio"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: Re-save the icons in another editor or use any image converter.

Comment: I agree with @wOxxOm , I had the same issue, and after I changed the icon to a generic one, it worked perfectly, and after that, I realized that my previous icons were corrupted.